# How to make a round menu around a floating button in android

Tags: android, button, menu, floating

I want to make a round menu around a button I already made. I found the class to make the floating button over the internet and used it. I try to make this button as a menu so when I click on it, it shows a menu around it with Home, Edit, and New buttons. I tried to post snapshot pictures to but I do not have enough reputations do to so...
This is the class I used:

```
 import android.app.Service;  
 import android.content.Intent;  
 import android.graphics.PixelFormat;  
 import android.os.IBinder;  
 import android.view.Gravity;  
 import android.view.MotionEvent;  
 import android.view.View;  
 import android.view.ViewConfiguration;  
 import android.view.WindowManager;  
 import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;  
 import android.widget.ImageView;  
 public class FloatingFaceBubbleService extends Service {  
   private WindowManager windowManager;  
   private ImageView floatingFaceBubble;  
   public void onCreate() {  
     super.onCreate();  
     floatingFaceBubble = new ImageView(this);  
     //a face floating bubble as imageView  
     floatingFaceBubble.setImageResource(R.drawable.floating_bubble);   
     windowManager = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);  
     //here is all the science of params  
     final LayoutParams myParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(  
       LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
       LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
       LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,  
       LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,  
       PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);  
     myParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;  
     myParams.x=0;  
     myParams.y=100;  
     // add a floatingfacebubble icon in window  
     windowManager.addView(floatingFaceBubble, myParams);  
     try{  
          //for moving the picture on touch and slide  
          floatingFaceBubble.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {  
         WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsT = myParams;  
         private int initialX;  
         private int initialY;  
         private float initialTouchX;  
         private float initialTouchY;  
         private long touchStartTime = 0;  
         @Override  
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {  
           //remove face bubble on long press  
              if(System.currentTimeMillis()-touchStartTime>ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout() && initialTouchX== event.getX()){  
                   windowManager.removeView(floatingFaceBubble);  
                   stopSelf();  
                   return false;  
              }  
              switch(event.getAction()){  
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:  
                touchStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();  
             initialX = myParams.x;  
             initialY = myParams.y;  
             initialTouchX = event.getRawX();  
             initialTouchY = event.getRawY();  
             break;  
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:  
             break;  
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:  
             myParams.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);  
             myParams.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);  
             windowManager.updateViewLayout(v, myParams);  
             break;  
           }  
           return false;  
         }  
       });  
     } catch (Exception e){  
       e.printStackTrace();  
     }  
   }  
      @Override  
      public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {  
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
           return null;  
      }  
 }
```

Can anybody help me to do this please?

Comment: You can upload your image on any online image up loader and post link of an image over here.